# Necesito construir un algoritmo que permita ajustar un arreglo

Tags: pseint

Debo hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

Si encuentra una casilla en blanco, debe mover los elementos hacia el inicio para ocupar ese espacio, la idea es que los espacios disponibles queden al final del arreglo.

Esto es lo que llevo, ya que no entiendo como puedo hacer lo de las casillas en blanco y moverlos al inicio, ya busque en videos y nada.

```
Proceso  ajustar_arreglo
Dimension arreglo_ajustado[10];

Definir i, arreglo_ajustado como entero;
Definir var_aux como entero;

i<-0;

para i<-0 hasta 9 Hacer
    arreglo_ajustado[i]<-azar(20);
FinPara

para i<-0 hasta 7 Hacer
    si arreglo_ajustado[i]>arreglo_ajustado[i+1] Entonces
        var_aux<-arreglo_ajustado[i];
        arreglo_ajustado[i]<-arreglo_ajustado[i+1];
        arreglo_ajustado[i+1]<-var_aux;
    FinSi
FinPara

Escribir '';
Escribir 'mostrar ordenado';
Para i<-0 hasta 9 hacer
    Escribir arreglo_ajustado[i];
FinPara
FinProceso
```

Comment: y esto porque no lo hace?? ese si arreglo_ajustado[i]>arreglo_ajustado[i+1] Entonces detecta los blancos? y que pasa si tenes dos blancos juntos?

Comment: no detecta los blancos lo que hace el arreglo_ajustado[i]>arreglo_ajustado[i+1] es ordenar los numeros dentro de el arreglo y no detecta blancos porque no se como poner, no se me ocurre algo para que los detecte dentro de ese ordenamiento que es por burbuja.

Comment: Ok una consulta  en este lenguaje el espacio es menor o mayor al ultimo numero?

Comment: eso dependera de el orden en que ponga arreglo_ajustado[i]>arreglo_ajustado[i+1] entonces

Comment: si lo pones asi es de menor a mayor

Comment: si lo pones asi es de mayor a menor arreglo_ajustado[i]<arreglo_ajustado[i+1] entonces

Comment: Agradesco la ayuda me ha costado mucho aprender a programar, la verdad es que me fascina el mundo de la programación pero me salen canas verdes y hay veces que me pongo a llorar y me frustro, pero se me pasa

Comment: No no.. pregunto como reconoce ese lenguaje a los espacios.. y para burbujeo falta un paso.. mañana te describo el algoritmo en pseudocodigo.. a ver si lo podes traducir

Comment: ok muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Burbujeo es un algoritmo que ordena una lista de a un movimiento por vez. Por lo tanto, va a recorrer la lista tantas veces como sea necesario hasta que la lista este totalmente ordenada.

Para ello se usa un flag que aclara si se hizo algún movimiento, y se recorre la lista de punta a punta moviendo los elementos necesarios.

En pseudocodigo, el algoritmo viene de la siguiente forma:

```
flag = true
Mientras flag = true
    flag = false
    Desde iniciolista hasta finlista-1
        si posicionactual < posicionactual+1
            cambiar las posiciones
            flag = true
        fin si
    fin desde
fin mientras
```

Fijate que esto ordena de mayor a menor toda la lista.. y la recorre tantas veces como sea necesario.

Ahora, con el tema de los espacios, ya depende del lenguaje. En general todos los lenguajes tratan a los espacios como caracteres menores que los números y las letras, por lo tanto un ordenamiento así debería dejar los espacios al fondo. sin embargo, de no ser el caso, uno debería mandar los espacios al fondo antes de hacer esto, y contarlos, y tomar como fin de la lista, el ultimo espacio que no sea blanco.